# Predefined daterangepicker with date format

Tags: daterangepicker

I modified the example of `Predefined Ranges` from [www.daterangepicker.com](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#examples)
I tried putting the date derived from mySQL to replace the default from the example. But it's not working. It keep saying 'Invalid date' even from the other post on the net saying I can use the date format from PHP.

**script**

```
$(function(){
    if($('#rentalDate').length){
        var start=$('#rent_from').val();
        var end=$('#rent_to').val();
    }else{
        var start = moment();
        var end = moment().add(+3,'M');
    }
    console.log(start+'/'+end);
    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#rental-range span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
        $('#rentalDate').val(start.format('Y-mm-d') + ',' + end.format('Y-mm-d'));
    }

    $('#rental-range').daterangepicker({
        "autoApply": true,
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);

});
```

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/cuxm50k2/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use a different date format than the default MM/DD/YYYY, you need to specify that in your options.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cuxm50k2/2/

Updated options:

```
$('#rental-range').daterangepicker({
  autoApply: true,
  startDate: start,
  endDate: end,
  locale: {
    format: 'YYYY/MM/DD'
  }
}, cb);
```